# libncursesw.so.6: version `NCURSES6_TINFO_6.4.current' not found (required by tmux)

Tags: anaconda, conda, ncurses, conda-forge

I get the following error message

```
tmux: /home/lennartv/mambaforge/lib/libncursesw.so.6: version `NCURSES6_TINFO_6.4.current' not found (required by tmux)
```

If I want to run tmux. I already tried the following

```
conda install -c anaconda ncurses
conda install -c conda-forge ncurses
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

```
conda list
(base) conda list
# packages in environment at /home/lennartv/mambaforge:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h5764c6d_1005    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.18.1               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.5.7             hbcca054_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.5.7           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1          py310h255011f_3    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda                     22.9.0          py310hff52083_2    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    2.0.2              pyh38be061_0    conda-forge
conda-package-streaming   0.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cryptography              38.0.4          py310h600f1e7_0    conda-forge
fmt                       9.1.0                h924138e_0    conda-forge
icu                       70.1                 h27087fc_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.20.1               h81ceb04_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.39                 hcc3a1bd_1    conda-forge
libarchive                3.6.2                h3d51595_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.87.0               hdc1c0ab_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libmamba                  1.1.0                hde2b089_3    conda-forge
libmambapy                1.1.0           py310h1428755_3    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.47.0               hff17c54_1    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libsolv                   0.7.23               h3eb15da_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.40.0               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               hf14f497_3    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.2.0              h46fd767_19    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.10.3               h7463322_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              h516909a_1000    conda-forge
mamba                     1.1.0           py310h51d5547_3    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h27087fc_1    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.1                hd590300_1    conda-forge
pip                       22.3.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pybind11-abi              4                    hd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.4           py310h5764c6d_1    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 22.1.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.10.8          h4a9ceb5_0_cpython    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    3_cp310    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                h0f457ee_0    conda-forge
reproc                    14.2.4               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
reproc-cpp                14.2.4               hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.1             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.80         py310h5764c6d_1008    conda-forge
setuptools                65.6.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
toolz                     0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2022g                h191b570_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.13            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.38.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
yaml-cpp                  0.7.0                h27087fc_2    conda-forge
zstandard                 0.19.0          py310hdeb6495_1    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h6239696_4    conda-forge
```

`tmux` was installed using pacman:

```
(base) pacman -Qi tmux
pacman: /home/lennartv/mambaforge/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.13)
Name            : tmux
Version         : 3.3_a-7
Description     : Terminal multiplexer
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki
Licenses        : BSD
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : ncurses  libevent  libutempter  systemd-libs
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : tmux-plugin-manager
Optional For    : fzf  skim
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 1079.40 KiB
Packager        : Christian Hesse <eworm@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Sun 28 May 2023 10:53:04 PM CEST
Install Date    : Thu 08 Jun 2023 03:26:08 PM CEST
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
Description     : Terminal multiplexer
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki
Licenses        : BSD
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : ncurses  libevent  libutempter  systemd-libs
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : tmux-plugin-manager
Optional For    : fzf  skim
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 1075.40 KiB
Packager        : T.J. Townsend <blakkheim@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Mon 06 Feb 2023 07:55:42 PM CET
Install Date    : Wed 22 Feb 2023 05:21:21 PM CET
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

Further

```
(base) pacman -Qi ncurses
pacman: /home/lennartv/mambaforge/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.13)
Name            : ncurses
Version         : 6.4_20230520-1
Description     : System V Release 4.0 curses emulation library
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html
Licenses        : MIT
Groups          : None
Provides        : libncurses++w.so=6-64  libformw.so=6-64  libmenuw.so=6-64  libpanelw.so=6-64  libncursesw.so=6-64
Depends On      : glibc  gcc-libs
Optional Deps   : bash: for ncursesw6-config [installed]
Required By     : bash  gptfdisk  guile  htop  inetutils  lame  less  libcdio  libedit  libxml2  llvm-libs  nftables  nmon  nvtop  openshadinglanguage  pinentry  procps-ng  psmisc  readline  screen  skim  tcsh  texinfo  tmux  util-linux  xterm
Optional For    : alacritty
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : alacritty-terminfo
Installed Size  : 3.97 MiB
Packager        : David Runge <dvzrv@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Tue 23 May 2023 10:02:38 PM CEST
Install Date    : Thu 08 Jun 2023 03:42:57 PM CEST
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signaturew.so=6-64  libformw.so=6-64  libmenuw.so=6-64  libpanelw.so=6-64  libncursesw.so=6-64
Depends On      : glibc  gcc-libs
Optional Deps   : bash: for ncursesw6-config [installed]
Required By     : bash  emacs  fish  gptfdisk  guile  htop  inetutils  kitty-terminfo  lame  less  libcaca  libcdio  libedit  libxml2  llvm-libs  llvm14-libs  nftables  nmon  nvtop  openshadinglanguage  pinentry  pipewire  procps-ng  psmisc  readline  skim  texinfo  tmux  util-linux
                  vifm  xterm
Optional For    : alacritty  vlc
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : alacritty-terminfo
Installed Size  : 3.97 MiB
Packager        : David Runge <dvzrv@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Mon 02 Jan 2023 01:34:12 PM CET
Install Date    : Thu 05 Jan 2023 11:29:05 AM CET
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

Comment: can you inlcude the output of `conda list` for that environment?

Comment: Had to use pastebin

Comment: tmux isn't listed there - and the list shows ncurses6.3 while the error message looks for 6.4

Comment: That's true, tmux was installed using pacman, I added additional info. I don't understand why it even interferes with conda

Comment: `conda` preprends its own directories to `PATH` and other environment variables. When a program now looks for `libncursesw.so`, it will find the `conda` installed version first. Can you try `mamba install ncurses=6.4`?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try using a `conda` installed `tmux` instead

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller, this seems to be a promising pointer. I performed `mamba install ncurses=6.4` but it didn't work. Removing the `conda` sections from my `.bashrc` made `tmux` work again. So `export PATH="/home/lennartv/mambaforge/bin:$PATH"` is the culprit and I need to reverse it?

Comment: Regarding your second comment. I uninstalled `tmux` using `pacman` and performed `(base) mamba install tmux`. Then executing `tmux` aborts and yields `server exited unexpectedly`

Comment: have you added any `conda` related things manually to your .bashrc? If not, then you should be able to run `conda deactivate` while in `base` or to deactivate base by default run `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` once. This should ncurses from being picked up from conda

Comment: Appending to `$PATH` instead of prepending does not work either, seems the only way to make it work is to disable conda

Comment: `conda deactivate` seems to block indefinitely. I guess my conda environment is somehow messed up, I'll get back to you in a couple of hours

Comment: I basically "solved" it by removing the `conda` sections from my `.bashrc`. But this might be more of a workaround. Thanks for your input!